# Paging Insert bulk data into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking, bulkinsert, sql-merge

Maybe is a dumb question but how split/paging the insertion to let other operations update the same table.

I've two stored procedures, one that insert bulk data

Stored procedure `InsertIntoMyTable`:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT Column1, @Column2, 0
FROM MyOtherTable
```

Primary key of `MyTable` is `(Column1, Column2)`

And also have a `MERGE` operation to the same table `MyTable` but from another source, mostly update (the column3) but also can insert data into `MyTable`.

The problem is when the insertion on `MyTable` takes a lot of time 10 million records, the stored procedure that execute the `MERGE` must wait until the `InsertIntoMyTable` finishes.

When trying to solve this, added a paginated

```
DECLARE @Start INT = 1
DECLARE @End INT = 1000
DECLARE @Amount INT = 1000
DECLARE @Total INT

SELECT @Total = COUNT(Column1) FROM MyOtherTable WHERE Column2 = @Column2

WHILE (@Start<=@Total)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, Column2, Column3)
      SELECT Column1, @Column2, 0
      FROM (SELECT 
               Column1, 
               Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY Column1) rownumber 
            FROM MyOtherTable 
            WHERE Column2 = @Column2) x
      WHERE x.rownumber between @start and @end

   SET @start = @end+1
   SET @End = @End + @Amount
END
```

but still locking the table until the operation ends.

Note: The execution is not in a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution **IS** in a transaction - if you don't provide an *explicit* transaction yourself, SQL Server will use an *implicit* transaction.

And if you have more than 5000 operations (`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`) in a single transaction, SQL Server will drop individual row locks and instead do a **lock escalation** and instead **exlusively lock** the **entire table** - so no other operations are possible until that (possibly implicit) transaction has committed (or has been rolled back).

The part that inserts in blocks of 1000 rows shouldn't cause a lock escalation - but of course, any rows that's being inserted in the context of that transaction cannot be read or manipulated by another transaction at the same time.

Comment: I've change my code something like this.
WHILE (@Start<=@Total)
BEGIN
 BEGIN TRAN
  Insertion here...
 COMMIT TRAN
END

But still block until insert all rows.